# How to run custom program in initramfs

Tags: linux, embedded, kernel, boot, initramfs

I have built initramfs which I want to use for setting up dm-verity. For testing purposes I don't switch_root and after boot it stays in initramfs.  However I need the tool veritysetup. I have it precompiled and copied to /usr/sbin on initramfs, but when I run it on the platform it says - `/bin/sh: /usr/sbin/veritysetup: not found`. Any ideas how to make it execute?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done this.
For a hint let me first give a simple clue first.
For veritysetup command to work in your initramfs you also need to copy all the dependent libraries (same architecture) to your libs folder inside initramfs.